# Creating own Listview Layout - "LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView"

Tags: android, listview, layout

I am just watching some Android tutorial videos to get into it. 
Currently I am dealing with ListViews and I want to create my own ListView layout. 
Based on the tutorial my code (part of MainActivity) looks like that:

```
//        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, favoriteTVShows);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout, favoriteTVShows);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_mainListView);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String tvShowPicked = "You picked: " + String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tvShowPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

When using the first out commented line (simple_list_item_1) it works, but with my own layout (2nd line) unfortunately not.

This is my row_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="de.oetzi.introductionlistviews.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, the funnies thing, the stacktrace...
By the way, another newbie question: How can I derive from theh stacktrace which row in which class is the evil one?

```
04-14 17:17:47.269 406-406/de.oetzi.introductionlistviews E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView 04-14 17:17:47.272 406-406/de.oetzi.introductionlistviews D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 04-14 17:17:47.275 406-406/de.oetzi.introductionlistviews E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: de.oetzi.introductionlistviews, PID: 406
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                                                at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                                                                                at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2349)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2153)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15678)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15678)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1170)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:814)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15678)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15678)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15678)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15678)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15678)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15678)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                                at android.widge
```

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView` - Basically, `ArrayAdapter` accepts only one kind of view - a single TextView named `@android:id/text1`

Comment: take a look at the ArrayAdapter.getView source ...also check the documentation textViewResourceId parameter of the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that it can only put your data in one view item. So in your layout you need to specify one item (one TextView in your case). Change your xml file to look like this:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="15dp"/>
```

Comment: it is a kind of solution but there is better

Comment: @Selvin what is the better solution

Comment: Anything else. Like using a `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: @Shark that is true but it need to re-design the code and also ArrayAdapters are efficient for lists with one view

Comment: this way he needs to re-design the layouts. whats the difference?

Comment: @Shark removing couple of lines from xml is easier than writing a separate class and also changes previous Java codes

Comment: Thanks Pooya, as I wrote already above, that is one of two possible solutions and it helped me to understand the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

change your adapter -

```
    ArrayAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout,R.id.textView1, countryArray);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks Nirel, now I understand the actual problem. I have to refer to one specific TextView. Therefore, the other proposed solution (by Pooya) works too.